# Recycler View data has own recycler view data

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new in Android Development. Im creating an app which has Data in Recycler View From Firebase

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbwJa.jpg)

this Main data contain some sub data which i don't want to show in Main Activity i only want to show Main data after clicking on main data new activity open and sub data of Main data should show in 2nd recyclerview this recyclerview contain subdata of main data

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zSij.jpg)

i want that subdata recyclerview change according to Main data
for example:- if i click on #1 Main data subdata of #1 should be showing in recyclerview
and when i click on #2 Main data subdata of #2 should be showing in recycler view

please if anybody no how to do it tell me

Comment: This sounds pretty very feasible to me, either with Cloud Firetore or with Realtime Database. Have you tried something in code so far?

Comment: yup already done the Main Recyclerview and subdata recyclerview now i'm finding a way to change subdata according to Main data

Answer (score 0):

Step:1->So just pass the main data primary key(primary key-> from this key/Id you can call the main-sub data from firebase) in the the second activity.

Step:2-> In the second activity make a recycler view with header and show the Main data in header and its sub-data in the list.

check this link how to add header on recycler view: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/get-ahead-using-headers-in-recyclerview-2909a69b19

Comment: im using Second Recyclerview in Fragment how to send key to fragment

Comment: brother either change your question or create a new one for this question because my answer will change the context of your main question it became difficult if someone come and read.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67356333/i-want-to-pass-firebase-primary-key-to-link-two-database-with-each-other